# Portable way to check if directory exists [Windows/Linux, C]

Tags: c, file, directory, file-exists

I would like to check if a given directory exists. I know how to do this on Windows:

```
BOOL DirectoryExists(LPCTSTR szPath)
{
  DWORD dwAttrib = GetFileAttributes(szPath);

  return (dwAttrib != INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES && 
         (dwAttrib & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY));
}
```

and Linux:

```
DIR* dir = opendir("mydir");
if (dir)
{
    /* Directory exists. */
    closedir(dir);
}
else if (ENOENT == errno)
{
    /* Directory does not exist. */
}
else
{
    /* opendir() failed for some other reason. */
}
```

But I need a portable way of doing this .. Is there any way to check if a directory exists no matter what OS Im using? Maybe C standard library way?

**I know that I can use preprocessors directives and call those functions on different OSes but thats not the solution Im asking for.**

**I END UP WITH THIS, AT LEAST FOR NOW:**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int dirExists(const char *path)
{
    struct stat info;

    if(stat( path, &info ) != 0)
        return 0;
    else if(info.st_mode & S_IFDIR)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *path = "./TEST/";
    printf("%d\n", dirExists(path));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: how about simply trying to create a file (with a random filename) in it?

Comment: Note that any answer you get from such a test is immediately out-of-date.  The directory you just checked can be deleted or moved by the time you use it - this type of code is inherently buggy.  This type of "check-then-use" bug even has [it's own Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use):  "In software development, time-of-check to time-of-use (TOCTOU, TOCTTOU or TOC/TOU) is a class of software bugs caused by a race condition involving the checking of the state of a part of a system (such as a security credential) and the use of the results of that check."

Comment: If you need to create a file in a specific directory, **just create the file in that directory**.  If the directory doesn't exist, you'll get an error.  And checking if the directory exists first does **NOT** guarantee that you can create that file, so you have to handle creation errors anyway.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

[stat()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) works on Linux., UNIX and Windows as well:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

struct stat info;

if( stat( pathname, &info ) != 0 )
    printf( "cannot access %s\n", pathname );
else if( info.st_mode & S_IFDIR )  // S_ISDIR() doesn't exist on my windows 
    printf( "%s is a directory\n", pathname );
else
    printf( "%s is no directory\n", pathname );
```

Comment: Checked this on Xubuntu 12.04 and Windows XP, it worked, thanks!

Comment: @alk: are you sure? I added an example code to my first post, it worked without any preprocessor directives with no warnings (I use gcc on Xubuntu and MinGW on Windows)

Comment: @alk I tried before posting, no preprocessor directives needed

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt: You did use which compiler/environment?

Comment: However in my frist comment when referring to windows I was implying the use of VC.

Comment: @alk it's an antique MS compiler (from VS 6.0 as far as I can see). I've looked into the stat.h and found that under some circumstances `stat` is defined as a macro, under other circumstances as a function.

Comment: @alk: so is there a way (for Windows) that would be portable at least for MinGW and Visual?

Comment: @ivy: Sorry guys, I seem to have been wrong: `stat()` compiles seamlessly on VC10. I cleanup my comments.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work on OSX 10.11. XCode7 said: "no matching function for call to stat". The fix though was for me to do pathname.c_str() in the stat() call because my pathname was a std::string.

Comment: Where's the MSDN documentation page for `stat`, as opposted to `_stat`?

Comment: @martin to be honest I've never searched for a documentation. I've jous found that the ported code compiled and worked as expected

Comment: With C++17 you can use `std::filesystem::is_directory` See answer by @Ivan Nikitin.

Comment: @MasterHD good point, but the question is tagged, C, not C++

Answer (score 22):

With C++17 you can use `std::filesystem::is_directory` function (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/is_directory). It accepts a `std::filesystem::path` object which can be constructed with a unicode path.

Comment: Thank you for this, seeing as this is part of the standard library and does not require bloated 3rd party libraries this should be the accepted answer

Comment: This answer is not for c, it's c++.   But that's the same ol' crap from stackoverflow.

Answer (score 9):

Since I found that the above approved answer lacks some clarity and the op provides an incorrect solution that he/she will use.  I therefore hope that the below example will help others.  The solution is more or less portable as well.

```
/******************************************************************************
 * Checks to see if a directory exists. Note: This method only checks the
 * existence of the full path AND if path leaf is a dir.
 *
 * @return  >0 if dir exists AND is a dir,
 *           0 if dir does not exist OR exists but not a dir,
 *          <0 if an error occurred (errno is also set)
 *****************************************************************************/
int dirExists(const char* const path)
{
    struct stat info;

    int statRC = stat( path, &info );
    if( statRC != 0 )
    {
        if (errno == ENOENT)  { return 0; } // something along the path does not exist
        if (errno == ENOTDIR) { return 0; } // something in path prefix is not a dir
        return -1;
    }

    return ( info.st_mode & S_IFDIR ) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: On Linux, at least, you would need to provide special handling for `ENOTDIR`, too.

Comment: @JohnBollinger , Thanks for your suggestion.  I've edited the reply to include it as it appears to make sense.  However, in my testing I failed to trigger this case.  I don't quite understand the man pages for stat and this error.  How does someone trigger this in a test?

Comment: `ENOTDIR` indicates that one of the names in the given path, *other than the last*, exists but is not a directory.  So, trying to stat `/tmp/regular_file/foo` should elicit this error, supposing that `/tmp/regular_file` is indeed a regular file.  This is to be distinguished from statting `/tmp/non_existent/foo` or `/tmp/foo/non_existant`; these latter two should both error with `ENOENT`.

Comment: I am not going to downvote. But if you are going to provide a clearer example, it would be nice to also include the necessary includes. Nothing on the entire stack overflow page (your answer and others) mentions "#include <errno.h>". But from other reading I've done, I know that is a missing import.

Comment: On MSVC compilation I didnt get error for errono, on GCC compilation I did get it.

Answer (score 6):

Use [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm), that will give you a portable way of doing those kinds of things and abstract away all ugly details for you.

Comment: oh I doubt that in C there will be a portable way to do this. You'll just have to use `#define` to check what OS your code is being compiled for and add for every OS you want to compile for.

Comment: Not everyone is willing to increase and bloat their code base for a single simple function when the standard library has a way to deal with it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GTK glib](http://www.gtk.org/features.php) to abstract from OS stuff.

glib provides a [g_dir_open()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-File-Utilities.html#g-dir-open) function which should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The above examples does not use [_access]1 which can be used for both Windows and Linux.
Code sample (Windows) to test with [stat]2, _access() and latest filesystem's [exists]3.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
std::vector<std::string> DirPaths
{
  "G:\\My-Shcool-2021-22",
  "\\\\192.168.111.8\\Oaco\\RotData\\VV-VA",
  "\\\\192.168.111.15\\5500\\C-drive\\Oaco\\RotateEarthProject",   "\\\\192.168.111.18\\d$\\Mercurial\\Workspace\\HideMoon\\Win32\\Debug", 
"Z:\\SuperSaver" //mapped network drive; symbolic link
};
/* test if the path is a directory
*/
void TestDirExists ()
{
int erno =-1;
struct stat  info {};
auto ErrorMsg = [&](std::string path) 
{
    _get_errno(&erno);
    if (erno == EACCES)
        cout << "access denied  " << path << endl;
    else if (erno == ENOENT)
        cout << "dir path not found  " << path << endl;
    else if (erno == EINVAL)
        cout << "invalid parameter  " << path << endl;        
};

for (const auto &dp : DirPaths)
{
    erno = -1;
    if (stat(dp.c_str(), &info) != 0)
        ErrorMsg(dp);        
    if (_access(dp.c_str(), 0) != 0)
        ErrorMsg(dp);       
    if (fs::exists(dp)==0)
        ErrorMsg(dp);
    if(erno < 0)
         cout << "#Dir Found: " << dp << endl;
}
```

}
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/access-waccess?view=msvc-170
[2]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions?view=msvc-170
[3]: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/exists